# Any way to see how many characters have been typed into the terminal in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, input, timer, buffer

Im using fgets but also alarm so I have a way to execute code whilst my user is still entering input. What I want to do is get a count of the current number of characters the use has input since the last time they pressed enter.
this is my current code. Basically I want to be able to move the cursor back to the start position + current number of characters typed so it doesnt overwrite.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int time_left = 25;

void moveTo(int row, int col)
{
    printf("\x1b[%d;%df", row, col);
}

void move_cursor_to_input_pos()
{
    moveTo(2, 15);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void update_timer(int signum)
{
    // check how many bytes are currently in the input buffer
    int bytes_waiting;
    int res = ioctl(1, FIONREAD, &bytes_waiting);
    if (res == -1)
    {
        perror("ioctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (time_left >= 0)
    {
        moveTo(0, 15);
        fflush(stdout);
        time_left -= 1;
        if (time_left < 10)
            printf("%d ", time_left + 1);
        else
            printf("%d", time_left + 1);
        moveTo(3, 15);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("res: %d, bytes: %d", res, bytes_waiting);
        move_cursor_to_input_pos();
        alarm(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    moveTo(0, 7);
    printf("Time:  ");
    moveTo(2, 7);
    printf("Input: ");
    moveTo(3, 7);
    printf("Chars: ");
    signal(SIGALRM, update_timer);
    alarm(1);
    while (time_left > 0)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            char input[100];
            if (fgets(input, 100, stdin))
            {
                moveTo(10, 10);
                printf("You entered: %s", input);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Here you can see the timer is non blocking, however it always resets cursor back to the start of the line.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8hFg.jpg
if I had already typed 1234 then it updates the timer I want to put the cursor after the 4 not back one the 1. `ioctl` but I cant get it to do anything

Ive tried to use

Comment: If you want this level of control you should be using ncurses. You can't do it with stdio and serial input from the terminal.

Comment: With fgets, you can't. Use ncurses for your text ui if you need this kind of functionality. Or just put the terminal in a mode, where getchar gives you every character immediately and use that (write your own getline function).

Comment: AFAIR there is no standard way. You need to use either a library or OS functions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this ended up solving my problem even if it isnt the exact way I thought I would need to solve it.
this escape code `printf("\x1b[s");` saves the current cursor position
this escape code `printf("\x1b[u");` restores the saved cursor position

So I can just do the save before I move to the timer location and restore after. Works perfectly
https://i.stack.imgur.com/88mXM.jpg